# Underscore before a C function parameter

Tags: c

I was looking through the source codes for the C CoreUtils, and I found this code that I don't recognize:

```
printf (_("Usage: %s [OPTION]...\n"), program_name);
```

Why is there an underscore before the format string?  What does it do?

Comment: Looks like someone have defined function or macro named `_`.

Comment: Note that if you suspect something _might_ be a macro, you can compile with `-E` to see what the code looks like after preprocessing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually (and conventionally in many, but not all, free software) `_`  is a `#define`-d macro for something like [gettext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gettext.3.html), to ease [internationalization & localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) of software.